# Return type 'NSDictionary *' must match previous return type 'void' when block literal has unspecified explicit return type

Tags: ios, methods, nsdictionary, google-places-api

Sir I am using google place Autocomplete and I am finding coordinate of a place I am using below code but i found an error in returning statement-

there are 5 places name  and placeID in finalarray

```
-(NSDictionary * ) checkArr
{
    NSLog(@"%@",finalarray);

    NSDictionary *dict = [finalarray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *placeID = [dict objectForKey:@"place_ID"];

    NSDictionary * dict1 = [self getquardinate:placeID];

    return dict1;
}
```

I am finding above error in return statement while returning dictionary

```
- (NSDictionary * )getquardinate:(NSString*)placeID{
  [_placesClient lookUpPlaceID:placeID callback:^(GMSPlace *place, NSError *error) {

  if (error != nil) {
      NSLog(@"Place Details error %@", [error localizedDescription]);

      return ;
  }

  if (place != nil) {

      NSNumber *lat = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:place.coordinate.latitude];
      NSNumber *lon = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:place.coordinate.longitude];
      NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:lat, @"latitude",lon, @"longitude", nil];

      return dict; // above error in this line
  }
 }];
}
```

Comment: It's an asynchronous interface and you are treating it as synchronous.  It's a bit broad to cover here as it's a fundamental concept that would take a fair amount of explaining.

Comment: Then Sir what should I do to handel it. i want coordinates in another function.

Comment: You will need to restructure that code completely, however not before you understand how an asynchronous interface works compared to a synchronous one.  There are plenty of questions about it here, however you are better off looking for dedicated articles elsewhere on the net.

Answer (score 0):

Your block has one plain return statement (returns void) and one statement return dict (returns an NSDictionary*). That's not allowed.

If you had defined the return type of the block as void, the second would give an error. If you had defined the return type of the block as NSDictionary*, the first would give an error. If you had defined the return type of the block as NSInteger, both would give an error.

You didn't specify the return type, leaving it to the compiler. After the first "return" the compiler thinks "well, return type must be void" so you get an error message on the second return.

PS. As trojanfoe remarked, you need to figure out how asynchronous calls work. What you are trying to do *cannot* possibly work that way. Another PS: What is a quardinate? Are you from Texas where "coordinate" sounds like "quardinate"?

Comment: That's about as clear as mud.  Also what about the sync/async issue?

Comment: What is unclear? A block has two return statements that don't match. The compiler _must_ complain. And a callback can easily have a non-void return value.

Comment: I think a more optimal way of saying that is that the `return` type must match that declared by the block.

Comment: That block is declared without a return type.

Comment: Which implies `void` which implies `return;` (or nothing).